# Mixed characteristic in symplectic geometry

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, mirror-symmetry, p-adic

Are there any mixed-characteristic phenomena in symplectic geometry/mirror symmetry?

There are papers on symplectic geometry by Abouzaid (inspired by Kontsevich--Soibelman, I believe) in which there is some rigid-analytic geometry over an equal characteristic field going on. There is also a paper on HMS by Lekili--Polishchuk working over $\mathbb{Z}$, so there might be some examples there (but I have a feeling that their paper is kind of a toy model, the first step in the study of something largely unknown).